# Database trigger vs stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I have columns "column1", "column2", and "column3" in the table "table1".

- "column1" is the PK, the ID.
- "column2" is a Boolean, 'Y' or 'N'.
- "column3" is a reference to "column1" when the record is a child of another record:

For example:

[image: EXAMPLE COLUMNS]

When column3 == NULL AND column2 is updated to == 'Y'

- I need the database to update column2 == 'Y' where column3 == column1;

[image]

In the above image, I want column 2 to update to 'Y' in the bottom 2 rows.

Would a trigger work better to handle this, or would a stored procedure work better (or, some other solution)?

Comment: To add some conceptual clarity, row 1 is a parent to row 2 and 3. If another row was added with column3 == NULL or 2(any value != 1), row1 would not be it's parent.

Comment: Triggers are executed as a result of INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE operations. Procedures are "manually" executed.

Comment: Personally I would use a trigger unless it causes you performance issues. In that case you could use a scheduled stored procedure.